# JSON in PHP can't transmit Strings

Tags: javascript, php, json, database, transmitfile

**Solved**
Hello everyone I want to transmit an json from php to an js file and id works.
However if I want to transmit an String in the Json it doesn't work.
The Debuger says JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Test" if you know an other way id would be great also.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('','root','','JobBlocks');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM JobBlocksDaten";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$DB_inhalt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$datenzUE = "{\"name\": Test, \"age\": 31,}";
echo $datenzUE;
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/jQuery&PHPnew/tst.php",
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    var Daten = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(Daten.name);
    alert(Daten.age);
    }
    })
    })
    })

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="sub">Submit result</button>
    <main id="main">
    </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What happens if you try `$datenzUE = "{\"name\": \"Test\", \"age\": 31,}";`

Comment: It doesn't work Property name must be a string literal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Comment: thx @tephyr id probably would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON strings need to be quoted, and the last element can not have a trailing comma, so you'd need this:

```
$datenzUE = "{\"name\": \"Test\", \"age\": 31}";
```

But that's a bad idea. You're best off using `json_encode()`, which will do all the quoting and escaping for you:

```
$array = ['name' => 'Test', 'age' => 31];
$datenzUE = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: thank you very much  will accept you answer asap

Comment: The first approach doesn't work Error text(SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Property name must be a string literal)

Comment: Well, I did say not to use the first approach. :)